# Wikitude: How to remove/replace the wikitude logo and add the API key to remove 'Beta' watermark

Tags: ios, ios4, augmented-reality

How to remove/replace the wikitude logo and add the API key to remove 'Beta' watermark?
Are there any documentation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating your own overlay, the logo will be replaced by your own, as described here: http://www.wikitude.org/enadd-overlay-ar-2

You can get your API key here:
http://www.wikitude.org/developers
more specifically:
http://w4client.mobilizy.mobi/w4/jsp/keyGenerator.jsp

(you might want to try and phrase your question a bit better next time. I had to guess at what you meant. Try and write in complete sentences.)

Hope this helps!